# php regex strange error

Tags: php, regex

i use such regex `$msg = preg_replace('/<b>(\w)<\/b>/', '9999', $msg);` to replace `<b>test</b>` but it not replace. why?

Comment: You need `\w+`. Else it matches only a single letter within the `<b>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the plus after \w+

```
 $msg = preg_replace('/<b>(\w+)<\/b>/', '9999', $msg);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the quantity token. That would only match one character long strings between the `<b>` tags.

```
$msg = preg_replace('/<b>(\w*)<\/b>/', '9999', $msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$msg = preg_replace('#<b>(\w)*<\/b>#', '9999', $msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `\w` does not match. I don't find my regex manual right now, but use something like `.*`.